# overlap plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting year-month `periodIndex` as x, and variable as y. I have the following function to produce the plot:

```
def visualize_ilf(pandas_df):
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (30,9)
    pandas_df['idx'] = pandas_df.index # is monthly
    ax1 = pandas_df.plot(x='idx', y='dep_score')
    ax2 = pandas_df.plot(x='idx', y='message_counts')
    ax3 = pandas_df.plot(x='idx', y='hasQuestionMark_INT')
    ax4 = pandas_df.plot(x='idx', y='sharing_ind')
    return plt.show()
```

This works fine, but I get separate plots for each y. How can I overlap the plots?

Comment: if the answer solved your question, accept it. If it helped you, upvote it. If it didn't, tell what happened when you tried that. I've seen many of your recent questions, where you just ask the question and then keep quiet. This is not acceptable. Please accept the answers if they solved your question.

Answer (score 2):

To reuse the same plot (or subplot), pass the ax as a parameter to the next one. Also, as you're using the index as `x`, you don't need to create a special column for it, just omit the `x` as parameter to the plot and pandas will use the index as `x`. You can use `plt.xlabel` to properly label the x-axis.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def visualize_ilf(pandas_df):
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (30,9)
    ax1 = pandas_df.plot(y='dep_score')
    ax2 = pandas_df.plot(y='message_counts', ax=ax1)
    ax3 = pandas_df.plot(y='hasQuestionMark_INT', ax=ax1)
    ax4 = pandas_df.plot(y='sharing_ind', ax=ax1)
    plt.xlabel('My x label') # set a label for the x-axis
    plt.show()

N = 30
df = pd.DataFrame({'dep_score': np.random.normal(50, 10, N),
                   'message_counts': np.random.normal(60, 10, N),
                   'hasQuestionMark_INT': np.random.normal(70, 10, N),
                   'sharing_ind': np.random.normal(80, 10, N)},
                  index= range(N))
visualize_ilf(df)
```

[image: example plot]

Alternatively, in this case you can simply put multiple columns as the `y` parameter:

```
ax1 = pandas_df.plot(y=['dep_score','message_counts','hasQuestionMark_INT','sharing_ind'])
```

Comment: Is your question still open?